# Add image on active, togglable tab HTML/CSS

Tags: css, html, navigation, uinavigationbar

I am trying to create a "togglable tab" navigation bar for my webpage. I've figured out how to create the togglable tabs by following a w3schools tutorial, but I am not trying to figure out how to modify its appearance so that it has an upward arrow pointing towards the active tab like the image below. Does anyone know of a way to achieve this?
[image: How to get upward arrow?!?!!?]

Here is my code for the tags:

```html
    <ul class="navtabs">
        <li><a href="#" class="tablinks" onclick="openLink(event, 'about')">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="study.html">How to Study</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="tablinks" onclick="openLink(event, 'help')">Helpful Links</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="tablinks" onclick="openLink(event, 'comment')">Comments</a></li>
    </ul>
    
    <div id="about">
        <h1>About</h1>
        <p>HERE IS A DESCRIPTION OF ABOUT THE SITE YADAYADA</p>
    </div>
    <div id="help">
        <h1>Helpful Links</h1>
        <p>THERE WILL BE LINKS HERE JUST U WAIT</p>
    </div>
    <div id="comment">
        <h1>Comments</h1>
        <p>U CAN LEAVE COMMENTS HERE ABOUT UR OWN TIPS/TRICKS FOR STUDYING</p>
    </div>

    <script>
        function openLink(evt, linkName){
            var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
            tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
            for(i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++){
                tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
            }
            tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
            for(i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++){
                tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
            }
            document.getElementById(linkName).style.display = "block";
            evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
        }
    </script>
```

Okay, so I discovered through inspecting the element that the page uses a border-bottom and then this image of an upward arrow
[image: Upward arrow]

How would I get an image to appear on a tab when it is active?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out by simply adding this to the CSS

```html
ul.navtabs li a:focus, .active{
    background-image: url(../../arrow.png);
    background-position-x: center;
    background-position-y: bottom;
    background-size: initial;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    
}
```

I get this result:

[image]

Now I've got to figure out how to make the border-bottom wrap around the arrow.png. If anyone's got any idea how to do that I'd greatly appreciate it. I don't think it'll be to hard to figure out a work around, though.

Answer (score 1):

Add new class to < li> element ("active" e.g.) and style it (class::after) with image. Then use Javascript (jQuery will be good too if you use it on your website) and remove this class when other menu element will be clicked (also add this class to clicked element).